# LaTeX Exam Package: change the mark position for long questions for \pointstorightmargin

Tags: packages, exam

I am working on an exam papers and all is fine except the position of the marks to long questions more than two lines.

I use the `\pointstorightmarin` to place the marks in certain position. It is ok when the question is short (in one single line), but it has problem when the question is more than 2 lines where the mark is placed in the first line (as the exam package says).

Could you help to add a few lines so that I can use `\pointstorightmargin` for the whole papers but I can change the position for certain long questions? (just like the picture shows)

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Johnny

```
\documentclass[11pt, addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,multicol,enumerate}

%PRINT ANSWERS

%\printanswers

\bracketedpoints

\pointsinrightmargin

\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{1.4cm}

\begin{document} 

\begin{questions}

\question  Consider the equation

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{\sin x}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\cos x}=2 \sqrt[4]{8}, \quad 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2} \text {. }$$

\begin{parts}

    \part [2] Given that $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, verify that $x=\frac{\pi}{8}$ is a solution to the equation.\textbf{I want the marks right after the question but not in the first line.} 

    \part [5] Hence find the other solution to the equation.

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried a few different ways but failed. Thank you so much.

Comment: @kolegr Thanks so much. I just put one line \pointsdroppedatright and then all the marks are missing. My latex file has 8 questions, I need to add \droppoints to every question. Could it be possible that in a latex of 8 questions, I can use a few lines of codes to change the position of the marks for ONLY one question? Thanks

Comment: I dont know exactly who as been thancked, but my correct answer was the first one (You can control the time of the posts!).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,multicol,enumerate}

%PRINT ANSWERS

%\printanswers

\bracketedpoints

\pointsinrightmargin

\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{1.4cm}
\pointsdroppedatright %<-- line added (page 20 of doc)
\begin{document} 
    
    \begin{questions}
        
        \question  Consider the equation
        
        $$
        \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{\sin x}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\cos x}=2 \sqrt[4]{8}, \quad 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2} \text {. }$$
        
        \begin{parts}
            
            \part  [2]  Given that $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, verify that $x=\frac{\pi}{8}$ is a solution to the equation. \droppoints % <--code added
            
            \part [5] Hence find the other solution to the equation.We make this question longer to have at last two lines.\droppoints % <--code added
            
        \end{parts}
        
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```